# How to limit builds only for teamcity agents with installed gradle?

Tags: gradle, teamcity

I have one teamcity server and several agents. Not all of them has gradle installed.

How to limit builds only for agents with installed gradle?

Answer (score 0):

On your build configuration, go under 'agent requirements' and select 'add new requirement':

[image: agent requirement]

Include whatever value you want to check for. If Gradle isn't on the path variable, you can add a new variable to the agent and check for the presence of that.

You can check this has worked by looking at the agent compatibility for the build configuration.